# How to create file choosers similar to default windows boxes?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, save, jfilechooser

I want to create save and open dialogue box using Java Swing `JFileChooser`, but when I created it shows like first image:

[image]

But I want to create dialogue boxes like windows default dialogue boxes like in image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the best user experience of the file chooser, offer the file chooser in the default look-and-feel for the OS.

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
```

### Windows appearance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices

1. You could use java.awt.FileDialog instead. This would probably solve your issue on windows. I don't know if you need an fd to look like the windows fd on all platforms
2. You can make your own JDialog, add a JFileChooser to it (on the right), and replicate the buttons on the left.

Answer (score 0):

first you neeed to install latest version of Your NetBeans